# Не могу разобраться с анимацией слайдера

Tags: css, css3

Всем здравствуйте!
Есть вот такой код CSS:

```
.scontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    animation-name: slideranim;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-delay: initial;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@keyframes slideranim {
    10% {
        left: 0%;
    }

    20% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    30% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    40% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    50% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    60% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    70% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    80% {
        left: -400%;
    }

    90% {
        left: -400%;
    }

    100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

И вот это притормаживает анимацию, но траблы то в том, что анимация сразу приостанавливается:

```
.scontainer:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Не закончив промежуточную анимацию.

Теперь собственно вопрос, как реализовать, такое, чтобы слайдер при наведении прокручивал слайды допустим, второй слайд, прокрутился до конца, а не замирал допустим на:

```
left: 145%;
```

А прокручивал до конца и замирал, то есть, было бы:

```
left: 200%;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вот такой хак:**

Накрываем сверху слайдер прозрачным `<div>`, который будет забирать на себя событие hover. Остается только сделать анимацию `z-index` слайдера, чтобы в момент, когда он движется, он был под прозрачным `<div>`, а когда не движется — над ним:

```
....
10% { left: 0%; z-index:3; }
11% { z-index:0; }
19% { z-index:0; }
20% { left: -100%; z-index:3; }
30% { left: -100%; z-index:3; }
....
```

**Итого рабочее демо:**

Накрывающий `<div>` сделал с обводкой в целях тестирования, естественно обводку `border` нужно будет убрать

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  animation-name: slideranim;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-delay: initial;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

@keyframes slideranim {
  0% {
    z-index: 3;
  }
  10% {
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  11% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  19% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  31% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  39% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  40% {
    left: -200%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  51% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  59% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  60% {
    left: -300%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  70% {
    left: -300%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  71% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  79% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  80% {
    left: -400%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  90% {
    left: -400%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  91% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  99% {
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
}

.scontainer:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.scontainer>div {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}

.scontainer>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.hoverblock {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dotted #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverblock"></div>

<div class="scontainer">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Блестяще! Спасибо!